# cURL works but browser (through NGINX) won't load

Tags: nginx, unicorn, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using `NGINX` and `Unicorn` for my `Rails` app.  I've hit a brick wall and am not sure what is happening.

I have set `NGINX` logging to full debug.  When I attempt to browse to my site home page, I get problem loading page and nothing in the `NGINX` error log.  When I use `cURL` to get to the same page, it works perfectly and the log is full of helpful information.  I'm hoping this is an obvious error in my `NGINX` configuration file:

```
upstream unicorn-soup {
  server unix:/home/soup/app/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock;
}

server {
        listen 80 default;
        listen [::]:80 default;

        root /home/soup/app/current/public;

        server_name soup.quote2bill.com;

        try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @unicorn;

        location @unicorn {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_pass http://unicorn-soup;
                proxy_read_timeout 300s;
                proxy_send_timeout 300s;
        }
}
```

Note I even tried setting this to the default site and browsing to the IP address but it didn't help.

Thanks for your time and suggestions on how to troubleshoot and/or fix.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!  I had dropped the `location` directive for the `try` line.

Corrected:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @unicorn;
    }
```